# What does `i pos;` mean in C++?

Tags: c++, grammar

I saw a code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kiithsacmp/miniini/trunk/view/head:/miniini/src/inisection.cpp).

And about at line [137](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kiithsacmp/miniini/trunk/view/head:/miniini/src/inisection.cpp#L137):

```
inline bool INISection::ReadString(const char * name, const char * & out) const
{
    //...

    i tag_index;

    if(*name == '\0')
    {
        //...
        tag_index = Iter;
    }
    else
    {
        tag_index = BinarySearch(Tags, Length, name);
    }

    //...

    return false;
}
```

What does `i tag_index;` mean? Does C++ have this grammar?

Comment: Some stupid programmer made some stupid typedefs to obfuscate the code

Comment: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kiithsacmp/miniini/trunk/view/head:/miniini/include/typedefs.h#L21

Comment: `i` is probably a `typedef`. `typedef int i`, could be located in `#include "typedefs.h"` [from the link u shared]

Comment: Please, for your sanity, stop reading that code. It is produced by a terrible programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually an [int_fast32_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). Look at include/typdefs.h and find this at line 21:

```
typedef int_fast32_t               i;
```